# Tensorflow / Keras issue with a special architecture for physics-informed machine learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, architecture

I try to implement a special DNN architecture to be used for physics-informed machine learning. As you may know, in this architecture, partial differential equations are integrated into the loss function. The architecture of interest is plotted bellow:

[image]

As you may find, this special architecture allow us to evaluate differential operations such as `K.gradients(model.outputs, model.inputs[0])` which is the partial derivative of *Txy* with respect to *x*, and have it as part of the loss function.

Now, I would like to have the following architecture:

[image]

As you can find, this network has `(x,y)` as the input, `Txy` as an output, followed by gradient operations on `Txy` and then `(Uxy, V_xy)` as the final outputs. This architecture, however, results in the following error:

```
raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. ')
```

When I check the gradients of the loss with respect to the weights, I find that they are `None` right at the layers I define `(Grad_Txy_x, Grad_Txy,y)`.

Anyone knows what is the source of this error? How can I have intermediate layers that are some derivatives of some other layer with respect to the inputs?

---

Edited:

You can try the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import keras as k
import tensorflow as tf

def custom_gradient(y, x):
    return tf.gradients(y, x, unconnected_gradients='zero')

x = k.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='x')
y = k.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='y')

lay = k.layers.Dense(50, name='lay1')(k.layers.concatenate([x,y]))
lay = k.layers.Activation('tanh', name='tanh')(lay)

lay = k.layers.Dense(50, name='lay2')(lay)

Txy = k.layers.Dense(1, name='Txy')(lay)

dT_dx = k.layers.Lambda(lambda F: custom_gradient(F, x)[0], name='dTxy_dx')
dT_dx = dT_dx(Txy)

dT_dy = k.layers.Lambda(lambda F: custom_gradient(F, y)[0], name='dTxy_dy')
dT_dy = dT_dy(Txy)

lay = k.layers.Dense(50, name='lay3')(k.layers.concatenate([dT_dx, dT_dy]))
Uxy = k.layers.Dense(1, name='Uxy')(lay)
Vxy = k.layers.Dense(1, name='Vxy')(lay)

model = k.models.Model([x,y], [Uxy, Vxy])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

k.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=False, to_file='output.png')

for lay in model.layers:
    print(k.backend.gradients(model.total_loss, lay.output))

model.fit([np.ones((10,1)), np.ones((10,1))],
          [np.ones((10,1)), np.ones((10,1))])
```

The gradient evaluations show that the lambda layer is returning wrong gradients:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients/concatenate_1/concat_grad/Slice:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/concatenate_1/concat_grad/Slice_1:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_2/lay1/MatMul_grad/MatMul:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_3/tanh/Tanh_grad/TanhGrad:0' shape=(?, 50) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_4/AddN_1:0' shape=(?, 50) dtype=float32>]
[None]
[None]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_7/concatenate_2/concat_grad/Slice:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_8/concatenate_2/concat_grad/Slice_1:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_9/lay3/MatMul_grad/MatMul:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_10/AddN:0' shape=(?, 50) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_11/loss/Uxy_loss/sub_grad/Reshape:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_12/loss/Vxy_loss/sub_grad/Reshape:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I added two non-Linear functions right before the Lambda function (I commented them out so you can spot them easily). You don't necessarily have to add Tanh function (could be any non-linearity, e.g. Sigmoid).

```
import numpy as np
import keras as k
import tensorflow as tf

def custom_gradient(y, x):
    return tf.gradients(y, x, unconnected_gradients='zero')

x = k.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='x')
y = k.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='y')

lay = k.layers.Dense(50, name='lay1')(k.layers.concatenate([x,y]))
lay = k.layers.Activation('tanh', name='tanh')(lay)

lay = k.layers.Dense(50, name='lay2')(lay)
#lay = k.layers.Activation('tanh')(lay)  


Txy = k.layers.Dense(1, name='Txy')(lay)
#Txy = k.layers.Activation('tanh')(Txy)


dT_dx = k.layers.Lambda(lambda F: custom_gradient(F, x)[0], name='dTxy_dx')
dT_dx = dT_dx(Txy)

dT_dy = k.layers.Lambda(lambda F: custom_gradient(F, y)[0], name='dTxy_dy')
dT_dy = dT_dy(Txy)

lay = k.layers.Dense(50, name='lay3')(k.layers.concatenate([dT_dx, dT_dy]))
Uxy = k.layers.Dense(1, name='Uxy')(lay)
Vxy = k.layers.Dense(1, name='Vxy')(lay)

model = k.models.Model([x,y], [Uxy, Vxy])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

k.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=False, to_file='output.png')

for lay in model.layers:
    print(k.backend.gradients(model.total_loss, lay.output))

model.fit([np.ones((10,1)), np.ones((10,1))],
          [np.ones((10,1)), np.ones((10,1))])
```

Comment: Well, that is not what I want. Txy is my last output and should be remained linear, otherwise, I cannot train `tanh(Txy)`. And, mathematically, the first `tanh` layer is enough to have infinite number of derivatives! So far, I think the problem is due to algorithmic issue handling lambda layer when a gradient operation is applied, as I discuss here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13050